# Provider not registering with Jersey 2.8

Tags: java, spring, jersey, provider

I have a Jersey 1.x application which I am migrating to Jersey 2.8.  My .WAR depends on a .JAR file which contains a @Provider and @Component annotated class.

```
package com.usamp.core.ui.model.utility;

@Component
@Provider
public class UIModelObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UIModelObjectMapperProvider.class);

    private ObjectMapper
        uiModelObjectMapper;

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(final Class<?> type) {
        return
            Model.class.isAssignableFrom(type)
                ? uiModelObjectMapper
                : null;
    }

    public UIModelObjectMapperProvider() {
        LOG.debug("UIModelObjectMapperProvider Constructed");
    }

    public ObjectMapper getUiModelObjectMapper() {
        return uiModelObjectMapper;
    }

    @Resource
    public void setUiModelObjectMapper(final ObjectMapper uiModelObjectMapper) {
        this.uiModelObjectMapper = uiModelObjectMapper;
    }
}
```

I see that spring creates this @Component and properly configures it.  However, even though I am using this configuration, the @Provider is not utilized:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.usamp.biddingtool.utilities.BiddingToolConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.usamp.biddingtool.rest
            com.usamp.core.ui.model.utility
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I also tried using com.usamp as the only package and still the @Provider is not picked up in another JAR.

As a test, I created a brand new class and placed it along the classes with the .WAR:

```
package com.usamp.biddingtool.rest.providers.contextresolver;

@Component
@Provider
public class UIMapperProvider extends UIModelObjectMapperProvider {
}
```

As you can see, this class simply extends the class coming from the .JAR dependency.

When server starts up what I see is:

1. Spring creates the a bean to represent UIModelObjectMapperProvider and calls proper setters to configure dependencies
2. Spring creates the a bean to represent UIMapperProvider and calls proper setters to configure dependencies
3. Jersey creates a new object for UIMapperProvider and no dependencies are set

So it seems that Spring is doing it's thing, however, Jersey is:

1. Not seeing a @Provider in a dependent .JAR (not scanning across jars for packages?)
2. When a @Provider IS found with the .WAR a new object is created and Spring's bean is not used

I am using this to configure my application in web.xml:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
    <param-value>com.usamp.biddingtool.utilities.BiddingToolConfig</param-value>
</init-param>
```

My BiddingToolConfig class looks like this:

```
public class BiddingToolConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public BiddingToolConfig() {
        register(MultiPartFeature.class);
        register(UIModelObjectMapperProvider.class);
    }
}
```

I am also using the jersey-spring3 dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

In fact, my API methods ARE getting wired up correctly, so the following works:

```
@Path("bid)
@Component
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class BidAPI {

    @Resource
    private BidService
        bidService;

    @Resource
    private SFBidMappingService
        sfBidMappingService;
```

So it just seems that the @Providers are not being found when in a separate JAR, and when they are found, Spring is not utilized.

Temporarily, I created a new @Provider class in the .WAR and implemented it to forward the call to Spring's bean:

```
@Provider
public class UIMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(final Class<?> type) {
        return
            ApplicationContextProvider
                .getApplicationContext()
                .getBean(UIModelObjectMapperProvider.class)
                .getContext(type);
    }
}
```

But I should not have to do this.

Any idea what I am missing?

Thanks.
-AP_